# Как передать звук с микрофона по сети?

Tags: c#, c, delphi, c++

Нужно передать звук с микрофона по сети на другой комп и воспроизвести там. Я знаю, что мне нужна 2 программы. Сервер и Клиент. А еще я знаю, что я дожна использовать RTP. Я справилась с задачей c помощью FTP.  Думала, что и с этой справлюсь, но что-то не получается. Прошу помощь. Спасибо всем заранее.

Comment: @Диляра Не надо повторять однотипные вопросы.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [**New Audio Components**](http://symmetrica.net/newac/).
[**Здесь**](http://symmetrica.net/audio/index.htm) то же самое на русском языке

Answer (score 3):

По хорошему суть такова: берем поток с микрофона, режем на кусочки по 0.1-0.5 сек (смотря насколько вам нужен реалтайм, чем выше частота, тем больше нагрузка). Кодируем сей кусочек в mp3 и шлем по уже созданному сокет-соединению. Там, соотв-но, дешифруем и воспроизводим.

Собственно, если вас не сильно заботит траффик, можно решать в лоб(без перекодировки, в PCM MONO). В который раз тут пиарю [либу](http://un4seen.com), уж простите)

Чего делаем: инициализируемся, определяем девайс микрофона. Выставляем потоку глубину/частоту, чтобы ваше соединение вытянуло (ширина потока будет = *`(глубинаbps / 8) * 1 канал(моно) * частотадискретизации`* байт/сек).

Далее: открываем соединение с клиентом и раз в 0.1-0.5 сек берем с потока байты и шлем в сокет. С такой же частотой на клиенте считываем данные с сервера и напрямую воспроизводим.

Отправку/прием лучше реализовать в отдельном потоке.

В архиве для дельфей (скорее всего не только, но не проверял) куча примеров, которые можно расковырять. В т.ч. был пример с инет-радио. В том же архиве хелп по всем функциям, наложить их на алгоритм выше не должно быть проблемой.