# Как передать звук 8 кГц с микрофона потоком?

Tags: c++, аудио, потоки-данных

Использую оборудование: микрофон с усилителем + аналогово-цифровой преобразователь + микроконтроллер + Wi-Fi модуль.

Получилось записать оцифрованный сигнал в WAV файл с помощью цикла 8000 записей/сек. Кодирование не использовал, полученные байты просто писал в файл. [Пример WAV файл](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8pOl6hli7IqLVpsdUhReFRaUDA/view?usp=sharing)

1. Чем можно этот файл прослушать?

Таким же способом, как запись в файл, могу оцифрованный сигнал резать на куски по 2048 символов и передавать на сервер через TCP или UPD. На сервере принимаю пакеты.

2. Как эти пакеты обработать и воспроизвести в реальном времени?

Comment: 1. Где вы хотите этот файл слушать? 2. В какой среде программирования будет писаться клиент и сервер?

Comment: Прослушать бы на компьютере. Но как плееру сказать что там 8 кГЦ?
Писать планирую на С++ клиент-сервер

Comment: 1. Начать, видимо, нужно с понимания «что такое на самом деле [WAV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIFF)?». У формата есть заголовок, в котором указывается и частота записи. 2. В реальном времени через сеть воспроизвести практически невозможно — задержки сети при передаче пакетов, потеря пакетов. 3. На сервер можно передавать данные кусками, как есть. При получении кусок преобразовывать в WAV нужного формата и времени воспроизведения. И передавать в нужный класс для воспроизведения.

Comment: Подскажите где можно посмотреть пример такого класса? Если попадался он вам

Comment: Смотрите [соседнюю тему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/53835/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8?rq=1)

Comment: Если у вас настоящий WAV, то его  можно прослушать чем угодно, 99% игралок его понимают.

Comment: про плеер , лучше использовать нечто врде audioedition или иные программы для обработки звука.